# Handlebars not reading backbone.js model attributes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

i am having some strange difficulties showing model attributes with handlebars and backbone.js
here is the code.

> ```
> MYAPP.Menu = {};
> MYAPP.Menu.Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
> urlRoot : 'menuItem',
>         defaults: {
>         title: "Menu Item Title default",
>         price: "menu item price default"
>         },
> });
> ```

```
MYAPP.Menu.Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MYAPP.Menu.Item,
    url: 'menuItems'
});

MYAPP.Menu.ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize : function() {
        this.model = new MYAPP.Menu.Item();
        this.model.on('all', this.render, this);
    },
    render : function() {
        var source = $("#index-template").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        console.debug(this.model.get("title")); <- shows default value
        var html = template(this.model);
        console.debug(html);
        this.$el.html(html);
        return this;
    }
});
```

And the template:

> ```
>   <script type="text/x-mustache-template" id="index-template">
>         <div class="entry">
>          <h1>{{title}}</h1>
>           <div class="body">
>             {{price}}
>           </div>
>         </div>          
>     </script>
> ```

the output is nothing just the tags with out any data. no errors in console as well.
Any ideas?

**Well i have a solution:**

When i am using

> ```
>   initialize : function() {
>         this.title = "Menu Item Title default";
>         this.price =  "menu item price default";
>     },
> ```

Everything works fine. does anyone have an explanation for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var html = template(this.model);
```

should be

```
var html = template(this.model.toJSON());
```

Basically, `this.model` has an `attributes` property that stores all of the information that you can retrieve using `this.model.get()` and set using `this.model.set()`. These properties aren't attached to the base model.

When you have the following code

```
initialize : function() {
    this.title = "Menu Item Title default";  // BAD!
    this.price =  "menu item price default"; // BAD!
}
```

You are attaching the attributes to the base model. This is incorrect use of Backbone. If you tried doing `this.model.get("title")` afterwards, it would be `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesnt explain why when I use a constructor instead of default it works